# Django Model - Mix model fields and instance attributes in class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Not sure if I am on a completely wrong track, but I want some kind of a temporary runtime variable/field in my Django model. Currently I have this:

```
class BioChemicalProperties(models.Model):
    mw = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    iep = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    exco = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    molar_exco = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    e01 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    def get_protein(self):
        aa_seq = self.ab.get_lc_protein()
        aa_seq += self.ab.get_hc_protein()
        return aa_seq

    def calc_mw(self, aa_seq=None):
        if not aa_seq:
            aa_seq = self.get_protein()
        analysed_seq = ProteinAnalysis(aa_seq)
        self.mw = analysed_seq.molecular_weight() + 18.015

    def calc_exco(self, aa_seq=None):
        if not aa_seq:
            aa_seq = self.get_protein()
        analysed_seq = ProteinAnalysis(aa_seq)
        self.exco = analysed_seq.molar_extinction_coefficient()[1]
    
    #...more methods here...

    def calc_all_bioprops(self, aa_seq=None):
        if not aa_seq:
            aa_seq = self.get_protein()
        self.calc_mw(aa_seq)
        self.calc_iep(aa_seq)
        self.calc_molexco(aa_seq)
        self.calc_e01(aa_seq)
```

The `aa_seq` variable is a temporary value that should not be stored in the database. Nevertheless, to not re-compute the value for each method when multiple methods are to be used, I want to optionally give it as a parameter. I see that giving the `aa_seq` as a parameter in each method is redundant and also not object-oriented. Now I wonder if it is a good idea (and possible at all) to store it as a class property like:

```
class BioChemicalProperties(models.Model):
    mw = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    iep = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    exco = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    molar_exco = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    e01 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    aa_seq = ""

    def calc_mw(self):
        if not self.aa_seq:
            self.aa_seq = self.get_protein()
        analysed_seq = ProteinAnalysis(self.aa_seq)
        self.mw = analysed_seq.molecular_weight() + 18.015
```

However, I haven't found any similar examples where model fields and non-model fields were mixed...is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea's good, but your nomenclature is confused.

There's absolutely nothing wrong with storing it as an *instance attribute*.  It's not a field, and that it's on a model is coincidental.  Models are just special cases of classes.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#choices) is an example of non-field attributes being defined on a `Model` subclass in the Django docs themself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I implemented it and it indeed works as expected.

Comment: IMO this is valid (I've upvoted as well), but usually non-field attributes are used for something like constants (like the choices in the example). And with this approach it would be possible to set the value to something else, instead of making sure it's always a calculated field using `property` or `cached_property` (without a setter). Also wouldn't this need a constant check on whether this value has been calculated, so a bunch of `if not self.aa_seq: self.aa_seq = calculate()`?

Comment: @BrianD I must disagree with you entirely.  Examples of non-constant things I regularly use as non-field attributes are manager instances, field tracker instances, temporary variables, options classes, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something [**`cached_property`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) can do:

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class BioChemicalProperties(models.Model):
    ...
    @cached_property
    def aa_seq(self):
        return self.ab.get_lc_protein() + self.ab.get_hc_protein()
```

You can then just use `self.aa_seq` like you currently have, and you can remove the `if not aa_seq` checks as it's not needed anymore. Additionally this will cache the computed value of `aa_seq` for the lifetime of the instance without storing anything to the DB.

Comment: Hi @BrianD, thanks for your proposal. Although the initial simple approach of using an instance attribute seems to already do the trick, the cached_property was new to me and it looks like an interesting approach for other use cases!

Comment: All good! I've upvoted @Adam Barnes's answer, but with that approach keep in mind you will have to always check if `aa_seq` has already been calculated (`if not aa.seq`). Also it would be possible to set it to another value outside the instance, which can potentially introduce behavior you don't expect (like `instance.aa_seq = somerandomvalue`). But up to you